# Is this a malfunction of the ROUND function in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, backend, rounding, rdbms

In a project I am working on, I somewhat found myself doing the same computation at back end and front end. The computation is rounding off the product of a ratio of two numbers and another number i.e. the expression to round of is of the form

> x / y * n

In front end I am using JavaScript and back end I am using MariaDB. With x=41, y=60 and n=30, the front end gives me 21 which is correct, because

```
41 / 60 * 30
```

is 20.5 but MariaDB's implementation of `ROUND()` function gives me 20 when I pass to it this expression!

```
ROUND(41/60*30,0)
```

even though it (MariaDB) evaluates

```
41 / 60 * 30
```

to the correct result 20.5000

If I pass 20.5 (20.5000) to MariaDB's `ROUND()` function, the function gives back the correct result 21! I have summarised this mystery (to me at least) with the following SQL statement

```
SELECT 41/60*30, ROUND(41/60*30,0), ROUND(20.5,0), ROUND(20.5000,0)
```

whose output is below...

[image]

Is something wrong with the implementation of `ROUND()` function in MariaDB?

Comment: Rounding float/double 0.5 is always a lottery due to non-precise value (+- 1 in last digit).

Comment: Everyone who ever computes with floating point math should read a textbook introduction to computing with floating point math.

Answer (score 2):

This is a floating point precision issue; if you were to

```sql
SELECT CAST(41/60*30 AS DECIMAL(22,20))
```

You would get:

```
20.49999999000000000000
```

So when it gets rounded, you get 20. You can work around this by casting to a `DECIMAL` with less precision (e.g. `(5,3)`) or double rounding; for example:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(CAST(41/60*30 AS DECIMAL(5, 3))) AS crnd, ROUND(ROUND(41/60*30,3)) AS drnd
```

Output:

```
crnd    drnd
21      21
```

Note that you may get more precise results with floating point if you multiply before dividing.

Answer (score 0):

It is true like all are pointing out that

> this is a floating point precision issue

I may have found a shorter/simpler (not sure if works for all situations) workaround than the one proposed by [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick). We only cast the ratio to float and that is all... thus

```
ROUND(CAST(41/60 AS FLOAT)*30 ,0)
```

this gives the correct result

> 21

But still I wonder why ROUND() gives 21 and 20 with the 'same' input. Can someone give us the possible reason?

Comment: I think the point is that it's not the same input. If you `CAST(CAST(41/60 AS float)*30 AS DECIMAL(22, 20))` you get `20.50000011920929000000`, so that is why it rounds up to 21. I think you'll find the cast to decimal/double rounding method to be more reliable. For example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=e4df8feb2e7ac537f61fd5ce3d3b54b2

Comment: True! My workaround is not universal. I take your advice and so I go with 'cast to decimal/double'. Thank you so much.